# Change button sprites in scrollview Unity3D_5.2

Tags: unity, c#

I have a scroll view with lots of buttons on it. when i press one button, that button needs to change the sprite and stay like that. if any other button (or same one) is pressed previous button needs to revert back to original sprite.. 
here is some example [image]

button 2 was pressed and changed sprite, it stays like that untill it is pressed again or any other (in this case button 3) is pressed

Comment: Try rephrasing this in a way that turns it into a question. I'm unsure what information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [UIToggle](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Toggle.html) with [Toggle Group](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ToggleGroup.html) instead of doing it manually.

You can create multiple Toggle buttons having same Toggle Group then so only one button (toggle button) will be enabled at a time.

Comment: Thank you, i used your advice to learn more about toggles in unity and they work like charm..